# Which verb would you use in this case?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

> The shirt has been cleaned and it is in your drawer, Paul.
>
> Mom, it is spotted.

To explain that the pronoun *it* stands for (is this verb even correct?) "my shirt", which verb would you use?

1. The pronoun *It* **is referred/referring/refers to** the expression "my shirt"
2. The pronoun *it* **is pointing to/points to** the expression "my shirt"
3. The pronoun *it* **makes for** the expression "my shirt"

Comment: As an aside, "spotted" is probably not the verb we would use in this case!  I think we would probably say *stained*, or maybe it *has a spot*, but "spotted" implies a regular pattern of spots.

Comment: refers to, points to, "make for" won't do here, imo

Comment: 'refers to' is the best option in this case

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's just throw out ***makes for*** completely. That's not anywhere near a situation you could use that word in. Sorry.

Both ***refers/is referring*** and ***points/is pointing*** will be generally understood and acceptable, but *to point* sounds like you're talking to people with poor English and you aren't sure if they'll understand *to refer*. Unless you're talking to small children or early foreign-language learners and don't want to teach them the verb *to refer*, I would use ***to refer***.